# Improve wordpress security by hiding non public resources

Tags: htaccess, security, configuration

I'm new from wordpress and i want improve security of wordpress multisite  by hiding non public resources, eg. wp-admin, wp-config etc.

My setting seem to work, but i don't know if this setting can break something (core features, popular plug-in, etc.)

1. Are my settings good in general way?
2. My settings improve real security or i'm wasting my time?

httpd-vhosts.conf (apache)

```
# Disallow public access php for .htaccess and .htpasswd files
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

# Disallow public access for *.php files in upload directory
<Directory "/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/">
   <Files "*.php">
       deny from all
   </Files>
</Directory>

# Disallow public access for... 
<Files "wp-config.php">
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>

<Files "readme.html">
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>

<Files "license.html">
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>

<Files "license.txt">
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>

# Because we do not use any remote connections to publish on WP
<Files "xmlrpc.php">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# List of ACME company IP Address
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^127\.0\.0\."      NETWORK=ACME
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^XX\.XX\.XX\.XX$"  NETWORK=ACME
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^XX\.XX\.XX\.XX$"  NETWORK=ACME
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^XX\.XX\.XX\.XX$"  NETWORK=ACME

# Disallow access to wp-admin and wp-login.php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)admin-ajax\.php$ # allow fo admin-ajax.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:NETWORK} !^ACME$ # allow for ACME
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin\/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]

# Block user enumeration
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/?author=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,R=301]

# Block the include-only files.
# see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress (Securing wp-includes)
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
#RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L] # Comment for Multisite
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
```

function.php

```
<?php
// Remove unnecessary meta tags
// <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.1" />
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');

// Disable WordPress Login Hints
function no_wordpress_errors(){
    return 'GET OFF MY LAWN !! RIGHT NOW !!';
}
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'no_wordpress_errors' );
```

wp-config.php

```
<?php
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);
```

Comment: if you are new and unsure then check plugins like Sucuri Security,iThemes Security, Wordfence Security... those have multiple options.(It's not that i'm forcing you to use plugins but they have a solid userbase)

Answer (score 1):

Using `remove_action()` can be remove unnecessary links for example:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link'); //removes EditURI/RSD (Really Simple Discovery) link.
remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link'); //removes wlwmanifest (Windows Live Writer) link.
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator'); //removes meta name generator.
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head'); //removes shortlink.
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 ); //removes feed links.
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );  //removes comments feed.
```

Comment: Please use code formatting when you are posting code.

Answer (score -1):

Are you running your site on cPanel?

If so, explore your control panel and you'll see a few great modules.

- hotlink protection
- leech protection

Under **Advanced** tab, look for **indexes.** Once you click you can customize and "hide non public" resources very easily.

[image]

Comment: hot linking has nothing to do with security. You can be perfectly secure and allow hot linking and "leeching"

Comment: You are incorrect with that statement. I can't believe I got a downvote for posting multiple optimization techniques. (facepalm)

Comment: it is a facepalm if you do not know the difference between optimization and security :(.